# How to Manually Build An Order Function in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to build my own order function in R, that can order a vector of length 2.

This is the question I am asked to complete...
Write a function which takes one argument `x` of length 2, and returns the ordered
values of `x`.  That is, if `x_2<x_1`, your function should return `c(x_2,x_1)`, otherwise it
should return `x`.  (WRITE YOUR OWN FUNCTION. DO NOT USE THE BUILT IN FUNCTION ORDER)
This is the code I'm trying to use

```
x = (c(3,1))
orders = function(x){
  for(i in 1:length(x))
  if(x[i+1] < x[i]){
    print(c(x[i+1], x[i]))} else{
      (return(x))
  }}


orders(x)
```

but it's giving me this output with the error

```
[1] 1 3
Error in if (x[i + 1] < x[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

it's the right answer but I'm not sure how to fix the error, any suggestions?

Comment: Try with `for(i in 1:(length(x)-1))`

Comment: To expand on Marco's statement, the last time in the loop, `i == length(x)`, for which the `i+1` position does not exist. Be careful when indexing, this is a common problem in every programming language that allows numeric indexing of arrays. (And R is 1-based instead of 0-based, much to the chagrin or celebration of many.) BTW: it would be better to *return* a value instead of *printing* it, since the latter gives nothing back to the caller (that is immediately caught/stored without extra steps). Consider pre-allocating a vector and filling the positions as you go through the loop.

Comment: For the record, this function you are writing is not mimicking R's `order` function. That function returns the indices of the array/vector elements that would put them in sorted order. Your function here is returning the values themselves. For instance, R's `order(c(3,1))` returns `[1] 2 1`, indicating that the minimal value is in index position 2. The function you are mimicking is `sort` (or `sort.int`).

Comment: Do NOT use `for(i in 1:(length(x)-1))`. The proper R method is `for(i in seq_along(x) )`

Comment: @42- that's still wrong, as the OP is comparing `[i]` with `[i+1]`, so they would need to use either `seq_along(x)[-1]` (and switch to `[i-1]` and `[i]` internally) or `seq_along(x)[-length(x)]` (or `head(...,n=-1)`). Or use `for (i in seq_len(length(x)-1))`.

Comment: I wasn't trying to correct the question's code, but rather trying to discourage the flawed paradigm of `1:length(x)` or `1:(length(x)-1)` that was offered by Marco. I would have used `head(seq_along(x), -1)` to get the shortened result he offered..

Comment: Kristen, one reason 42- and I recommend against `1:length(x)` is that it is not robust to empty data. For instance, if `x <- numeric(0)`, it has a length of 0, which means you might expect the loop to not run at all. However, `1:length(x)` turns into `1:0` which, when you try it, returns a vector of length 2, certainly not what you intend. By using `seq_len` or `seq_along` (or some shortening of them), you are protected by this, as `for (i in seq_along(x))` will not run if `x` is empty. Similarly, `seq_len(0)` returns an empty vector (`integer(0)`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you say `x` is only of length two, why not something like:

```
my_order <- function(x) {
    if (x[1] < x[2]) {
        return(x)
    } else {
        return(rev(x))
    }
}
```

If the first element is less than second element, return the original vector; otherwise, reverse the order with `rev()`.

Try it for yourself with:

```
x1 <- c(3,1)
x2 <- c(2,3)
x3 <- c(101, -1)

my_order(x1)
my_order(x2)
my_order(x3)
```